# OpenStack LXD with conjure-up fails with a permission denied

Tags: openstack, lxd, conjure-up

I'm getting an error while trying to install [OpenStack LXD with conjure-up](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/conjure-up) on a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04.1, running in a VirtualBox VM.

```
$ sudo usermod -a -G lxd $USER
$ newgrp lxd
$ sudo snap install conjure-up --classic
$ conjure-up openstack-novalxd localhost
[info] Summoning openstack-novalxd to localhost
[error] Problem running lxd init: error: Unable to talk to LXD: Get http://unix.socket/1.0: dial unix /var/snap/conjure-up/common/lxd/unix.socket: connect: permission denied

[warning] Shutting down
Sentry is attempting to send 1 pending error messages
Waiting up to 10 seconds
Press Ctrl-C to quit
```

I can't figure out what am I missing.

Answer (score 0):

I had same the problem on Ubuntu 16.04. However once I used a fresh install of Ubuntu 17.04 including latest updates (this seems to be important) conjure-up worked as expected.

Comment: The OP's link clearly states it works with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and it should work on that platform. Being forced to upgrade the OS is unreasonable.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and it works after I reboot ubuntu.You need to reboot ubuntu after adding user to group and creating new group, before running conjure-up.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure `/var/snap/conjure-up/common/lxd/unix.socket` exists and has `lxd` as the group permission:

`sudo ls -l /var/snap/conjure-up/common/lxd
total 48
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 Jul 13 12:02 cache
drwx--x--x 2 root root 4096 Jun 29 10:45 containers
drwx--x--x 2 root root 4096 Jun 29 10:45 devices
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   60 Aug 17 11:58 devlxd
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 Jun 29 10:45 disks
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 Jun 29 10:45 images
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun 29 10:45 logs
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   24 Jun 29 10:45 lxd.db -> ../../current/lxd/lxd.db
drwx--x--x 4 root root 4096 Jul 12 11:39 networks
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 Jun 29 10:45 security
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1915 Jun 29 10:45 server.crt
-rw------- 1 root root 3247 Jun 29 10:45 server.key
drwx--x--x 2 root root   40 Aug 17 11:58 shmounts
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 Jun 29 10:45 snapshots
drwx--x--x 3 root root 4096 Jul 12 11:39 storage-pools
srw-rw---- 1 root lxd     0 Aug 17 11:58 unix.socket`